# RecyclerView with Retrofit2

Tags: constructor, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

I try to do recyclerView with retrofit2, but I do in my code: recyclerView Adapter Constructor and I get a error in my MainActivity part of this line -
 "(flowersList, this)": I get error: List anonymous retrofit2.Callback

```
RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter(flowersList, this);
```

my code my MainActivity is:

```
  try {
        APIService service = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(APIService.class);
        retrofit2.Call<List<Flower>> call = service.getFlowerData();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<List<Flower>> call, Response<List<Flower>> response) {
                List<Flower> flowersList = response.body();
                mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

                mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);

                RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter(flowersList, this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
            }
```

and the code in RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter is:

```
public class RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {
private List<Flower> mFlowers;
private Context mContext;

public RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter(List<Flower> flowers, Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mFlowers = flowers;
}


@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.flower_item_card, null);
    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
 holder.mTextViewTitle.setText(mFlowers.get(position).getName());

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(mFlowers.get(position).getPhoto()).into(holder.mImageViewFlower);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFlowers.size();
}
```

}

and my code in RecyclerViewHolder is:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView mTextViewTitle;
public ImageView mImageViewFlower;


public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView){
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    mTextViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    mImageViewFlower = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFlower);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

}

I try to do alot of thing but is still error.
thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a wrong context, try using `MainActivity.this` instead of `this`. Change this

```
RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter(flowersList, this);
```

to this

```
RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewFlowersAdapter(flowersList, MainActivity.this);
```